# Tensor prodct on Hilbert Space

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

How do I show that $\langle \phi|I \otimes I|\phi\rangle=1$ ? where:

$I$ is the identity operator and $\phi \in \mathbb{C^2}\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that $I\otimes I$ is the identity operator over $\Bbb C^2 \otimes \Bbb C^2$. From there, we're just noting that $\phi$ is a state (i.e. has magnitude $1$).